# Issue with Hoisting in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve few coding snippets and found the following snippet little tricky.

```
var x =100;
function test() {
  if(false) {
    var x = 200;
  }

  console.log(x);
}
test();
```

I expected that it will console 100 but instead it is printing undefined, I really dont understand how the hoisting is happening here as the false block will never execute. Could some one help me know the logic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right, it's caused by JS hoisting. Before ES2015/6 (`let`/`const` are block scoped similar to java), the scope of variable in JS are in a functional scope, which means all variables declared in a function will be moved to top of your function

```
var x =100;
function test() {
  if(false) {
    var x = 200;
  }

  console.log(x);
}
test();
```

will be interpreted as:

```
var x =100; // global var
function test() {
  var x; // local var

  if(false) {
    x = 200;
  }

  console.log(x); // climbing up the scope chain resolves to the closest local x, which is undefined.
}
test();
```

Answer (score 2):

Hosting happens regardless of conditions.

If it didn't, then it couldn't be hoisted until after the `if` statement was evaluated, in which case it still couldn't be hoisted because it would be too late.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var x =100;
function test() {
  // since you are declaring `var x` inside of the `test()` it ultimately compiles to this with hoisting
  var x;
  if(false) {
    x = 200;
  }

  console.log(x);
}
test();

// The method should be written like this if you want to use the outer `var x`
function test2() {
  if(false) {
    x = 200;
  }

  console.log(x);
}
test2()
```

Comment: @Xlee beat me to it :P

Comment: I like your example! We're working together try to share quality answers ;)

Answer (score 0):

think about it this way:

```
var x =100;
function test() {
var x ; //hoisted
  if(false) { //never assigned
    var x = 200;
  }

  console.log(x);
}
test();
```